# Is this session handler secure?

Tags: php, security, session

Are there any security vulnerabilities in this code?

```
class Session {
    private $id = array();
    private $data = array();
    private $name = 'session';

    public function __construct() {
        session_start();

        global $db;

        $this->id = isset($_COOKIE[$this->name]) ? $_COOKIE[$this->name] : $this->create_id();

        $id = $this->id;
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

        $check = $db->query("SELECT session_data FROM sessions WHERE session_id = ? AND user_ip = ? AND user_agent = ?");
        $db->execute(array($id, $ip, $user_agent));

        if ($db->row_count() != 0) {
            $this->data = $db->fetch_column();
            $this->data = unserialize($this->data);
        } else {
            $this->id = $this->create_id();

            $id = $this->id;
            $data = serialize($this->data);
            $time = time();
            $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
            $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
            $current_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            $insertion_data = array(
                'session_id'                =>      $id,
                'session_data'              =>      $data,
                'session_last_activity'     =>      $time,
                'user_ip'                   =>      $ip,
                'user_agent'                =>      $user_agent,
                'user_current_page'         =>      $current_page
            );

            $db->insert('sessions', $insertion_data);
        }
    }

    public function end() {
        global $db;

        $this->garbage();
        $id = $this->id;
        $data = serialize($this->data);
        $time = time();
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        $current_page = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

        $name = $this->name;

        // note to self: create update function in db class
        $db->query("UPDATE sessions SET session_data = ?, session_last_activity = ?, user_ip = ?, user_agent = ?, user_current_page = ? WHERE session_id = ?");
        $db->execute(array($data, $time, $ip, $user_agent, $current_page, $id));

        @setcookie($name, $id, time()+3600, '/', '');
    }

    public function create_id() {
        return strtoupper(md5(rand(-1000000, 1000000)));
    }

    public function garbage() {
        global $db;

        $expiration = time() - '2419200';

        $db->query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE session_last_activity < ?");
        return $db->execute(array($expiration));
    }

    public function regenerate() {
        global $db;

        $old_id = $this->id;
        $new_id = $this->create_id();

        $this->id = $new_id;

        $db->query("UPDATE sessions SET session_id = ? WHERE session_id = ?");
        return $db->execute(array($new_id, $old_id));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Rand() is not random

You should be aware that rand() is not as random as one might think. What if you create a session id that already exists? Consider replacing rand() or checking if the session id already exists.

### Bruteforce

Your session id is too easy to bruteforce. A session id should be treated as a password from a security point of view. The longer and more complex the session id is, the harder it is to bruteforce. Use session_regenerate_id() as it will give you a fairly good alpha-numeric ID.

Comment: Ah, damn! I was going to add a check to see if the session already existed, must've forgotten. Thanks for the points. :)

Answer (score 3):

Nope. Let's walk through it from a hypothetical attackers point of view.

> Okay. It's sending an identification cookie. It's hex. 32 digits long.
>   Probably an md5 hash. I wonder what's hashed? I'll throw it in
>   oclHashcat to check. I can make a billion guesses a second, so if it's
>   a hash of something simple, I'll find out.
>
> <3 seconds later>
>
> Huh. It's a number. Lemme grab another session and see if that's a
>   number too.
>
> Yep.
>
> It looks like these are all 6 digit numbers. I'll grab 10 more to
>   check.
>
> Okay, 6 digits AND they can be positive or negative.
>
> That's a keyspace of about 2^21. If there are 8 sessions going right
>   now, then it costs, on average,
>
> 2^(21 - 1 - 3) requests * 1 KB per request * 0.08 $/GB
>   ...
>   =1.01 cents to crack a session.
>   Alright, I'll start on that and see what I have in the morning.

So: Add more entropy.

Comment: Thanks, definitely useful! Could you be so kind as to give a bit more detail on how to prevent this? I understand what's going on, but not how to stop it from occurring. :S

Comment: Don't use MD5, use Blowfish.

Comment: @user555 so that's all it requires and I'll be (more or less) protected from attacks? That simple? o.o

Comment: Also use a unique random salt. This will prevent rainbow attacks and make the cracking more expensive. See "Don't use MD5" under my answer.

Comment: I'm slightly confused. I did a little research on the subject, multiple websites said that encrypting the session ID is pointless. The MD5 is only there to make the random string 32 chars in length.

Comment: On second thought your correct. You should probably drop MD5 and rand() in favor of session_regenerate_id(). The important part here is to make each session id random, so one session id can not be used to guess another one. Based on the new research I have edited my answer.